# Is there any way in C# to find the corresponding function according to the function name, like python

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

In python, I can find the corresponding function with the function name like this:

```
### testa.py
def funca(a=0, b=1):
    print("aaa", a, b)

def funcb(a=2, b=3):
    print("bbb", a, b)

func_dict = {"a": funca, "b": funcb}

def main():
    inp = input()
    if func_dict.get(inp):
        func_dict[inp](1, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I implement the similar function in C#?

Comment: In exactly the same way. .NET provides dictionaries and delegates. I'd expect `Dictionary<string, Action<int, int>>` for the example you've provided, though you can also use `Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg..., TArgN, TResult>` for methods that return something, or even create your own delegate.

Comment: [Dictionary docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0), [Delegates docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), [Action delegate docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-6.0), [Func delegate docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-6.0)